# Static methods on boostcentric factory implementation

Tags: c++, boost, static-methods, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement a C++ factory class that also perform the self registration of some derived classes. My implementation is based on the library:

http://arcticinteractive.com/2008/10/06/boost-centric-factory-pattern-implementation/

that is based on the Boost library. Just to give you a quick overview of this library, here is a simple self-explained (I hope) example:

```
struct foo { virtual ~foo() {} };
struct bar : foo { bar(int i) { std::cout << "bar() " << i << "\n"; } };
struct baz : foo { baz(int i) { std::cout << "baz() " << i << "\n"; } };

...

typedef factory< foo*(int) > myfactory_t;

myfactory_t f;

// Register a default (operator new) creator function
// for an implementation type
register_new_ptr<bar>(f, "bar");
register_new_ptr<baz>(f, "baz");

// Create objects through the factory
foo* fooimpl1 = f["bar"](1234);
foo* fooimpl2 = f["baz"](4321);
```

What I'm trying to do is to delegate each class to self-register them self to the factory using a static method. Here is the code:

animal.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "factory.hpp"
#include "abstract_factory.hpp"
class zoo;

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::factory;

class animal{
  virtual const std::string do_sound() const = 0;
  std::string name_;
  int age_;
  zoo* myZoo_;

public:
  animal(const std::string& name, int age, zoo* myZoo) : name_(name), age_(age), myZoo_(myZoo)
  {}

  virtual ~animal() {}

  const std::string sound() const
  {
    return do_sound();
  }

  const std::string& name() const { return name_; }
  const int age() const { return age_; }
};

template <class T>
struct animalFactory{
    typedef factory< animal*(std::string&, int, zoo*) > myfactory_t;  
    static const myfactory_t* f;

    static bool registerAnimal(const std::string& animalname){
            return register_new_ptr<T>(&f, animalname);
    };
};
```

When I try to register a class like:

crocodile.cpp

```
#include "crocodile.h"

bool r = animalFactory<crocodile>::registerAnimal("crocodile");
```

I get an error from visual studio 2012 that is:

```
animal.h(41): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'bool boost::factory::register_new_ptr(Factory &,Factory::id_param_type)'
```

Could someone help me to understand what is going on here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show the definition of `register_new_ptr`.

Comment: **[GotW #49](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)**; also [C2893: _In general, the way to resolve a C2893 error is to review the function's signature and make sure you can instantiate every type._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8kw2xcc.aspx)

Comment: The problem is probably that you are passing a `const myfactory_t**` instead of a `myfactory_t&`.

Comment: template <typename T, class Factory>
bool register_new_ptr(Factory& factory, 
    BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME Factory::id_param_type id)
{
  return factory.register_creator(id, new_ptr<T>());
}